# Animation Nodes not working with blender 2.80 2.81 2.82

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I've been trying to make the animation nodes work with blender but no matter which version of blender I install they won't work.I do prefer using blender 2.80 or higher and I did notice online that some users managed to install them. No answer from them tho. Please help.

Comment: Hello, you can check common installation problems there : https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1240

Comment: No problem installing for me. What´specifically 'doesnt work'? Which release are you using?